# Python 'print' method always prints in the same cell, doesn't matter in what cell it is called

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a *jupyter* notebook that calls a method `compare_sizes()` that prints some lines when executed. The problem that I am having is that these lines are printed in a different cell that the one where the method is called from:

[image]

As you can see, the method is called from cell 22, but the lines are printed in cell 19. I tried restoring the kernel, but I get the same result. I have used this method in other notebooks with good results.

**EDIT**

I discovered that EVERYTHING I print is printed in cell 19.

Comment: try to delete this block and create another one, might be python cache error

Comment: @MarcioRocha I did, and the problem persists. I, even, created more cells using that method and them all write results in cell 19

Comment: maybe find the python cache folder in the project and delete it. then restart the kernel and run all cells

Comment: @MarcioRocha Nope, the same